# How to make an array of game objects

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I was wondering how I could make an array of game objects using only one image? For example, I have a picture of a cannon ball and a cannon and I want to make 10 cannon balls and be able to change each one of them individually. I have this script attached to a single cannon ball gameobject and I have made my array length 5 using the inspector.

I've tried using instantiate but all that happens is it clones it forever.

```
public GameObject[] cannonball;
public int i;
public int x=0;
void Start()
{
    for (i = 0; i < cannonball.Length; i++) {
        Instantiate(cannonball[i], new Vector2(x, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        x = x + 5;
    } 
}
```

When I do this, for some reason it continues to clone game objects and I don't know why.

Comment: Yes this is using unity thanks!

Comment: What kind of object is this script attached to?

Comment: Well I am in unity 2D so just a sprite

Comment: I'm curious if it's on a cannonball, if it's on a cannon, or something else.

Comment: This script is on my cannon ball. I have a cannon gameobject in place and every time I press space I want it to fire a cannon ball. If I press space lets say 3 times, you can see 3 cannon balls moving across the screen.

Comment: Try removing this script from the cannonball and attaching it to the cannon instead. When you instantiate an object, it copies all of the scripts and other components attached to the original as well.

Comment: As an aside, why are `i` and `x` declared at the class level? `for(int i=0;...)` is perfectly valid...Oh, and you don't need `x` at all. `new Vector2(i * 5, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You attached this script to a canonball GameObject. This means that everytime you fire a canonball, this will have the script attached to it as well and spawn a new canonball spawning a new canonball... You can see the loop here.

You should not attach this to a canonball prefab, but rather on for example a GameController object.

I haven't tested it, but to do this, create a new GameObject in your scene and attach your script to it after removing it from your cannonball GameObject..Now if you press space you can instantiate the cannonballs.

```cs
public GameObject[] cannonball;
public int i;
public int x=0;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        for (i = 0; i < cannonball.Length; i++) {
            Instantiate(cannonball[i], new Vector2(x, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            x = x + 5;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: How can I do this

Comment: @Trucing Put the script on *literally anything else* besides your prefab.

Comment: Okay, and how can I make each of the cloned objects an image in my array through the inspector?

Comment: Or how can I move an instantiated object?

Comment: @Trucing https://answers.unity.com/questions/938559/how-to-move-instantiated-object-to-pre-defined-pos.html

Comment: @Trucing please accept the answer that solved your issue.